# how to execute commandButton having show popup behaviour and action event

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

```
//I'm having a command button like 
   <af:commandButton text="Validate"
                        binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Second.cb2}"
                        id="cb2"
                        action="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Second.cb2_ClickAction}">
                        <af:showPopupBehavior popupId="p11" />
 </af:commandButton>
//Popup dialog contains
<af:popup id="p11">
<af:dialog id="d2"
dialogListener="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Second.getAddressDialogListener}">
<af:panelLabelAndMessage label="Enter the Password for DataSource " id="plam13"/>
<af:inputText label="password" value="#{backingBeanScope.backing_Second.password}" id="it455"/>

</af:dialog>
</af:popup>
//Dialog listener in backing bean having
    public void  getAddressDialogListener(DialogEvent dialogEvent) {
    System.out.println("" + this.getPassword());
        SampleJdbc.DB_PASSWORD=this.getPassword();}
```

cb2_ClickAction in backing bean returns onestring and by using this string,redirected to next page.
My requirement is when i click on validate it will ask for the password in popup and get that password and then calls cb2_ClickAction and redirected to next page.It is not working.

Comment: Why are you using "BackingBean" scope?  Also, version of JDev/ADF will us help us help you better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the commandbutton only to show the popup

```
    <af:commandButton text="commandButton 1" id="cb1">
      <af:showPopupBehavior popupId="p1"/>
    </af:commandButton>
    <af:popup id="p1">
      <af:dialog id="d2" dialogListener="#{PopupBean.myDialogListner}"/>
    </af:popup>
```

and use the dialogListener to validate the password and redirect

```
public void myDialogListner(DialogEvent dialogEvent) {
    if(dialogEvent.getOutcome() == DialogEvent.Outcome.ok){
        FacesContext fctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        try {
            fctx.getExternalContext().redirect("untitled1.jspx");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Action should be used for navigation ONLY (= best practice, not rule). 
How about use ActionListener event and show the popup from the backing bean. Code example [here](http://oracleadf-java.blogspot.com/2012/11/popup-component-in-oracle-adf.html).
AL fires before Action, so you can evaluate user actions and choose to return string for navigation or not.

Answer (score 0):

Showpopup behavior cancels action event. So both can't go side by side. In your case try to execute the popup behavior from within actionlistener code using render kit classes.